# How to remove localstorage once per day?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which caches in local storage a big set of terms from sharepoint.
As the source data might change once or twice per day, I would like to include that if its a new day, then it should get fresh data.

App is used by 400 people so caching improved it a lot, from 15 seconds load to less than 1 second, but I need to be sure at least once new data is loaded.

Question is:

How can I invalidate this key each day?

```
function GetAllTermsRecursive(){
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
    {
        //Check if data has been cached.
        if(typeof(localStorage.Terms)  !== "undefined")
        {   
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var terms=localStorage.Terms;
            var end = new Date().getTime();
            var time = end - start;
            alert('Execution time with cache: ' + time);
        }
        else
        {

            var start = new Date().getTime();
            //Current Context
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();           
            //Current Taxonomy Session
            var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);           
            //Term Stores
            var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();           
            //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
            var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_kl5tZjInn7STsFTzIE7n3Q==");          
            //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
            var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("31da4bc1-6429-499a-9d5e-be5e18b13c87");         
            var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();          
            context.load(terms);

            context.executeQueryAsync(function(){   
                var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator(); 
                var termList = "Terms: \n";                 
                    while(termEnumerator.moveNext()){                       
                        var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current(); 
                        var currentTermPath = currentTerm.get_pathOfTerm().split(';');
                        var children = tree.children;
                        termList += currentTermPath.get_name(); 
                        termList += currentTerm.get_name() + "\n";              
                    }
                    localStorage.Terms = termList;
                    var end = new Date().getTime();
                    var time = end - start;
                    alert('Execution time: ' + time);               
                },function(sender,args){            
                      console.log(args.get_message());              
                    });
        }           
    }
    else {
            alert("Cache not sopported in old browsers, please upgrade");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Every day, or every 24 hours?

Comment: Put a timestamp in localStorage whenever you do the query. Test if the current date is the same as the timestamp; if not, invalidate it.